# How can I filter searching in answers that belong to a deleted post?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// questions_and_answers
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------+---------+
| id |    subject    |           body         | related | deleted |
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------+---------+
| 1  | subject1      | question1              | NULL    | 0       |
| 2  |               | answer1                | 1       | 0       |
| 3  | subject2      | question2              | NULL    | 0       |
| 4  |               | answer2                | 3       | 1       |
| 5  |               | answer3                | 3       | 0       |
| 6  | subject3      | question3              | NULL    | 1       |
| 7  |               | answer4                | 6       | 0       |
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------+---------+
-- related column contains either NULL for questions or the id of its question for answers
```

As you can see in table above, both `answer2` and `question3` are deleted. So I want to filter them in the searches. The point is, I want to filter `answer4` either. Because it belongs to a deleted question *(`question3`)*. Any idea how can I do such filtering?

---

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT qa.*
FROM questions_and_answers AS qa
WHERE MATCH(subject,body) AGAINST (:entry)
  AND deleted = 0
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT :page, 10;
```

As you can see, it only filters deleted posts. It doesn't care about filtering the answers that are belong to a deleted question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one level of relation -- for any row *r* for which another row *r'* exists, so that *r'*`.related` = *r*`.id`, *r*.`related IS NULL` -- you can either left join the questions to the answers and check the question's `deleted` or use a `NOT EXISTS` to check, that no deleted parent record exists.

`LEFT JOIN` variant:

```
SELECT qa1.*
       FROM questions_and_answers qa1
            LEFT JOIN questions_and_answers qa2
                      ON qa2.id = qa1.related
       WHERE MATCH(qa1.subject, qa1.body) AGAINST (:entry)
             AND qa1.deleted = 0
             AND coalesce(qa2.deleted, 0) = 0
       ORDER BY qa1.id DESC
       LIMIT :page, 10;
```

`NOT EXISTS` variant:

```
SELECT qa1.*
       FROM questions_and_answers qa1
       WHERE MATCH(qa1.subject, qa1.body) AGAINST (:entry)
             AND qa1.deleted = 0
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM questions_and_answers qa2
                                    WHERE qa2.id = qa1.related
                                          AND qa2.deleted = 1)
       ORDER BY qa1.id DESC
       LIMIT :page, 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well questions and answers probably belong in separate tables; that way you don't have this problem. In that case you would probably use a simple join in a one-to-many relationship. You can mimic that with CTEs:

```
with q as (
    select * from questions_and_answers
    where related is null and deleted = 0
), a as (
    select * from questions_and_answers
    where related is not null and deleted = 0
)
select *
from q left outer join a on a.related = q.related
order by q.id, a.id;
```

If it's absolutely essential that the answer appear as it's own row:

```
with qa as (
    select *, max(deleted) over (partition by coalesce(related, id)) as deleted
    from question_and_answers
)
select * from qa where deleted = 0
order by coalesce(related, id), id;
```

I just realize that you're on MySQL so you might not have CTEs and/or analytic functions available. Hopefully this is still useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another `AND` operator to assert an existence of a removed parent using a correlated sub-query and modify your conditions to have a more optimal query overall:

```
SELECT qa.*
FROM questions_and_answers AS qa
WHERE MATCH(subject,body) AGAINST (:entry)
  AND deleted = 0
  AND (qa.related IS NULL OR
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM questions_and_answers qaa
      WHERE qa.related = qaa.id AND qaa.deleted = 1)
  )
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT :page, 10;
```