# How can I use COALESCE() in WHERE clause optimally?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Here is my query:

```
select coalesce(qa2.subject, qa.subject) as question_subject,
       qa.body,
       (select count(*)
        from viewed_items vi
        where coalesce(qa.related, qa.id) = vi.question_id
       ) as total_question_viewed
from questions_and_answers qa
left join questions_and_answers qa2 on qa.related = qa.id 
where body like ':entry';
```

As you know, MySQL optimizer can never use a index on this on `coalesce(qa.related, qa.id) = vi.question_id`. So any idea how can I write this query more optimal?

Comment: Give it a try `where vi.question_id in(qa.related, qa.id)`, Make sure you check explain plan for both queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the calculation with two separate subqueries:

```
select coalesce(qa2.subject, qa.subject) as question_subject,
       qa.body,
       ( (select count(*)
          from viewed_items vi
          where qa.related = vi.question_id
         ) +
         (select count(*)
          from viewed_items vi
          where qa.related is null and qa.id = vi.question_id
         )
        ) as total_question_viewed
from questions_and_answers qa left join
     questions_and_answers qa2
     on qa.related = qa.id 
where body like ':entry';
```

Indexes can be used for each subquery, so it should be faster overall.  By the way, you don't have to worry about `NULL` values, because `COUNT(*)` in a correlated subquery always returns a value.  If nothing matches, the value will be `0`.

Comment: Your question is completely correct. Thank you, upvote. It shouldbe noted I cannot use `IN` clause like `where vi.question_id in(qa.related, qa.id)`. Because it is not the same as `where coalesce(qa.related, qa.id) = vi.question_id`.

Comment: Also @Gordon, Please and please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883162/how-can-i-filter-searching-in-answers-that-belong-to-a-deleted-post) .. I guess just you're the one who's able to write a sexy answer for it.

Comment: @Martin AJ yes, you actually can use `where vi.question_id in(qa.related, qa.id)` if it will help -- but not alone, because you are correct that it isn't equivalent... so you need to use `where vi.question_id in(qa.related, qa.id) AND coalesce(qa.related, qa.id) = vi.question_id`.  The optimizer is a pro at productive laziness, and it will resolve the first predicate with an index if possible, then filter with the second.  This works becauae one is a superset of the other.